# python pandas astype not working properly when chained with sklearn encoder

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Pandas == 1.2.3 
sklearn == 0.24.2

Trying to convert multiple binary columns into 1/0 using Ordinal Encoder then changing their datatype to 'int8'

MRE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["True", "False", "True", "False", "False"], 
                   "B":["Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"],
                   "C":[1, 4, 1, 4, 4]})
```

Running following converts datatype to "integer64" and to "float16" to "float64".

```
bin_cols = ["A", "B", "C"]
df[bin_cols] = OrdinalEncoder() \
                .fit_transform(df[bin_cols]) \
                .astype('int8')
df.dtypes
>>> A  int64
>>> B  int64
>>> C  int64
```

If I take it out and perform

```
df[bin_cols].astype('int8').dtypes

>>> A  int8
>>> B  int8
>>> C  int8
```

It **correctly** converts to "integer8"

What could be the problem?

EDIT:
If I run the 2nd block of code twice it works...

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Please provide some sample data

Comment: In my Jupyter, it was `int8`!, However, I think this also would work: `astype(np.int8)`

Comment: @ashkangh at first try? If you rerun it it works however not on the first run.

Comment: This behaviour is not reproducible in `pandas 1.3.2` and `scikit-learn 0.24.2`

Comment: For me, it worked in the chain of methods!

Comment: @HenryEcker Maybe you forgot to delete 'etc...'? we are using same sklearn version and I think any version of pandas can reproduce creating df.

Comment: @ashkangh hm... Could you tell me your pandas, sklearn versions?

Comment: No I didn't mean your code is not reproducible the _behaviour_ is not. This code run in a clean workspace with the above listed versions produces 3 columns all of type `int8` consistently every time including the first.

Comment: I ran it on Google Colab, and it uses `pandas 1.1.5` and `sklearn 0.22.2`

Comment: @HenryEcker Ah! hm... I've did it myself on clean workspace and still having the problem.

Comment: i cannot reproduce your error too, on pandas 1.3.0 and sklearn 0.24.1

Comment: hm... tried this at home with `pandas 1.1.3`  and `sklearn 0.23.2` and can reproduce the problem exactly. Also trying with other encoders results in same problem.